# TIP120 Vs. a Big Battery

Tags: power-supply, transistors, control

I have a big battery (11.1V, 10c, 1300mAh), a load of about 0.319 Ohms, and a TIP120 transistor. Now I've heard about the wonders of the TIP120 before (and complaints too) on various Arduino forums. I'm not very knowledgeable in EE, as I've been mostly focused on low-level physics & math, but from looking at [the datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TIP120.pdf), I don't believe the TIP120 is capable of being a switching mechanism here. In fact, I feel like it may melt and/or burst into flames if I tried it.

Is my intuition correct here? (Will it blow out the TIP120 if I use it as a switch in this situation?)

Comment: This is a thoroughly bad idea from start to finish.  Not only is your load well beyond the capabilities of the transistor at this voltage, it is also beyond the designed power delivery rating of your battery.  Whatever it was you were planning to do **don't do it** - some of the possible failure modes are decidedly unpleasant.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I wasn't planning on running it for long. Isn't a 10c battery capable of delivering 13A for an hour? Again, I just know what I've read in a couple of hours surfing Wikipedia.

Comment: No, it is not.  And it is not something you should be using for this purpose.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well, would there be something better to use? (My load is essentially an inductor, and I don't plan on powering it for more than a second at the absolute maximum.)

Comment: "_Isn't a 10c battery capable of delivering 13A for an hour?_" The ten cells are in series (not parallel) so the current is the same in each. "_1300mAh_" = 1.3 Ah. Max current for 1 h = \$ \frac {1.3Ah}{1h} = 1.3~A \$. The Wh (watt-hour) rating will increase by a factor of 10 as the power will be VI for each cell.

Comment: @transistor That's the battery discharge rating, not the number of cells. I think the battery actually has 3 or 4 cells. I was basing my assumption off of RC sites like [this one](https://www.commonsenserc.com/page.php?page=c_ratings_explained.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. 10C discharge of a 1.3 Ah battery means it will deliver 13 A. Discharge time will therefore be \$ \frac {1.3Ah}{13A} = 0.1~h = 6~minutes \$.

Comment: What is your 0.3 \$ \Omega \$ load and what are you trying to do?

Comment: @transistor It's just an electromagnet. I'm looking around at MOSFET datasheets ATM to try and find something suitable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40398/discussion-between-coilkid-and-transistor).

Answer (score 1):

From datasheet, TIP120 absolute max current is 5A.

11.1V / 0.319 ohms is 35A.

Your intuition is correct.

Comment: Just Ohm's law is required to answer my question? I thought the 10c rating would have made it more difficult to answer.

Comment: I guess I'll go find a transistor that can handle 35+A, unless there's a "preferable" switching mechanism?

Comment: @CoilKid a relay or a mosfet may be a better solution here. Oh, wait, its a inductive load? at 35 Amps? Ouch.

Comment: @Passerby I'm guessing a high-speed relay would be better then? My previous circuit used a LED current driver, but it supplied a constant current by slashing the voltage (I think.) My load is actually an electromagnet, but I assumed "inductor" would be a better word choice. I'm also trying to build this in a way that minimizes fire/explosion risks, so..

Comment: @Passerby I did a bit of looking around, would [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/STP120NF10/497-4118-5-ND/721366) be a suitable switching device? ([datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/1e/4b/01/7d/dd/d8/41/f3/CD00003356.pdf/files/CD00003356.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003356.pdf)) I'm thinking maybe, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @CoilKid. That mosfet is a great choice. I see it being used in many UPS supplies. Be sure to heat-sink it because it will get very hot at 35 amps. Still, this should be powered in short pulses to avoid damage to the battery.